# C function with if return

Tags: c, function

Im writing a code in C for college that involves the game rock(0)-paper(1)-scissor(2)-ecshe(3). The game should run with random numbers for both Player. In the end I have to get statiscal date of how often one player has won and how often rock(0)-paper(1)-scissor(2)-ecshe(3) apperead.
When I write a single code I can get all the information.
But when I am using a function I get only zero to calculate the statiscal data.

The value for Player_1 is always set as rock(1) in one of the rounds. The function is to calculate how many times Player_2 got paper(2) or scissor(3)

Making long story short:
How do I create a function to return me to possible answer according to the condition?

```
 int gewinn_summe_a(int spl_2, int a, int b , int c, int d){
         if(spl_2== a){
             return ++b; //the counter for a variable that i have in the main function
        }else if(spl_2==c){
             return ++d;
        }
        // return 0;

    if (player1 == 0) //this if set the value for player 1
        if (player2 == 1 || player2 == 3){ //this 'if' says that the player2 can have this two option


    //When the code below inside the program it does what is suppose to do:
    //calculate how many time player2 gave option 1 or how many time he gave option3

          if(spl_b==1){
             count_sh_b++;
          }else if(spl_b==3){
             count_ec_b++;
          }


    //However, when i use the function, I always get zero as the counter.

gewinn_summe_a(1,  count_sh_b , count_ec_b,  spl_b)

         printf("Contador SH B %d\n", count_sh_b);
         printf("Contador EC B %d\n", count_ec_b);
         printf("Spieler A: %d - %s\n", taste ,spiel_name[taste]);
         printf("Spieler B: %d - %s\n", spl_b ,spiel_name[spl_b]);
         printf("Player 1 A WON\n\n");
```

Comment: You're passing the `a` ... `d` arguments **by value** - so they won't be modified in the calling code (if that's what you want, pass *pointers*).

Comment: By passing as pointer, how should i declare them in the main function. And whete should it be poiting to in the main function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the counters *by reference*, like this:

```
int gewinn_summe_a(int spl_2, int a, int *b, int c, int *d)
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you call it by giving the addresses of the caller's variables:

```
gewinn_summe_a(spl_b, 1, &count_sh_b, 3, &count_ec_b)
```

BTW, your source is terrible, because it is incomplete, bad indented, and the variable names are mindlessly chosen.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.
Im new in the platform and it was quite difficult to write the code.
What do you suggest for me to improve my writing?
The original code was written in german, i tried to write here down just a piece of it.

Comment: A) To help us help you, a [example] is a prerequisite: the source must be error-free compilable at maximum warning level without any modification, and the executable must show the unexpected result. However, it must be as short as possible. B) Choose an indentation style and stick to it. C) You call `gewinn_summe_a()` with 4 arguments but it has 5 parameters. D) You return something but do not evaluate it. -- Please, get a good book and learn some basics. There are lots of them, even in German. ;-) Good luck!

Comment: I'll write it better than, if you can help me ok, if not, life goes on...